# Programmatically retrieve memory offset of C struct members w/o hard-coding member names

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling

I have a small program which I use to print the offset of struct members using the `offsetof()` operator.

I use this program in many contexts, where the structs in question are different and so I need to reprogram the code for each project (and for each modification I make to the structure). Since these structures tend to be pretty big (control and state structs), the update consumes lots of time.

What I would like to have is a method where I can use `offsetof()` equivalent, but where the 2nd parameter would be the member's name, given as a string, instead of hard-coding it in the statement.

To simplify, lets assume that the structures are comprised of single- and arrays of- 32-bit words, so the offset is always a multiple of 4.

Also, instead of name strings, an alternative method is welcome.

[*Note that although the members are all word-sized, still calculating the address just by counting members is not a good solution since the compiler may add padding between members. As one answer (which was removed) suggested, using the packed attribute can solve the problem by removing the paddings, this is not a valid solution as the actual application which defines the structure may use the padding for optimizing memory accesses*]

Answer (score 4):

You make "symbol table" arrays of the form:

```
#define S struct mystruct
#define X(m) { #m, offsetof(S, m) }
static const struct table {
    const char *name;
    size_t offset;
} table[] = {
    X(member1),
    X(member2),
    /* ... */
};
```

Then you can have a function which loops over table searching for a given name, and obtains the offset. You can have multiple such tables, one for each structure, all using the same search function. If you have so many members that the linear search performance becomes a problem, you can binary-search or add a hash.

Comment: Thanks. This looks promising and I will give it a try in the next project. however, if I get it correctly, you still need to hard-code the names as argument to the X() macro... I was hoping for an even more flexible solution were I can just feed the program with a list of names and the rest is done automatically. However - there's probably not much difference with the suggested method in terms of programming effort.

Comment: BTW, I think the declaration should be `table[]`?

Comment: Yes, I omitted that. Thanks. Fixed.