# Passing a struct member NAME to function in C?

Tags: c, struct, member

Is there any simple ways to pass the name of a struct member to a function in C? For example if I want to make this happen:

(I know the code is incorrect, I just wrote it to explain the question)

```
struct Test
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    struct Test t;
    t.x = 5;
    t.y = 10;

    example(t, <MEMBER NAME>);
}

void example(struct Test t, <MEMBER NAME>)
{
    printf("%d", t.<MEMBER NAME>);
}
```

Comment: You could use the member [offset](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/offsetof.3.html), but not the name.

Comment: Conceptually the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/13653024/2564301, right?

Comment: You could use a macro instead of a function. This could get weird quickly for a more complex function, but for your needs, you could do `#define example(x, member) printf("%d\n", x.member)`. But that means you lose type safety (and some other things).

Comment: this is a feature of more modern languages (C#, Java, JavaScript, ..) and is generally called 'reflection'. C doesnt have it. You can use the various offset calculation tricks

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but here is a pretty close solution using `offsetof`:

```
struct Test
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

void example(void *base, size_t offset)
{
    int *adr;
    adr = (int*)((char*)base + offset);
    printf("%d\n", *adr);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct Test t;

    t.x = 5;
    t.y = 10;

    example(&t, offsetof(struct Test, y));
}
```

Comment: Note that only GCC (and workalike compilers) allow you to do address arithmetic on `void *`.  The C Standard does not allow that.  You would need to do: `int *adr = (int *)((char *)base + offset);` to be standard conformant.  IIRC, GCC will 'fess up if you prod it with `-pedantic`.